# Buffer overflow when running nytprofiler

Tags: perl, devel-nytprof

I am getting

> *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/uwsgi terminated

error when trying to run nytprofiler. How can I go about debugging this, and what could be the possible cause? I know that its some code change that is resulting in this error, because when I switch to a very old commit, it works fine. Since the number of commits is too damn high, I can't realistically go in for a "git bisect" kind of a thing.

Comment: Is `uwsgi` suiciding, or is it being killed? If it's the former, you'd need to debug `uwsgi`. it To debug a binary program, one normally uses `gdb`.

Comment: If you are referring to [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect), then go for it! You can completely automate `bisect` with a script that returns 0 (for OK) for "good" commits and !=0 for "bad" commits. Even for 4000 commits it will take only ln2(4000) ≈ 12 steps to find the ultimate bad commit.

Comment: see the note about the build-time environment variable `NYTP_MAX_SUB_NAME_LEN` in http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-6.03/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm#panic:_buffer_overflow_... though the default value is 500 characters.